# Delete rows from data frame that contain one or more of multiple substrings

Tags: r

I'd like to remove all rows from a data frame that match one or more of a vector of strings. Brief example:

```
words <- c("abcde", "cdefg", "fghij", "efghi", "abcd", "fgh")
numbers <- c(1:6)
dat <- data.frame(words, numbers)

> dat
  words numbers
1 abcde       1
2 cdefg       2
3 fghij       3
4 efghi       4
5  abcd       5
6   fgh       6
```

I removed all the rows from the data frame where the column `word` contains one or both of the `strings` "bcd" and "ghi" with a while-loop:

```
strings <- c("bcd", "ghi")

i <- 1
while(i <= length(strings)) {
    dat <- dat[grep(strings[i], dat$words, invert = TRUE),]
    i <- i + 1
}

> dat
  words numbers
2 cdefg       2
6   fgh       6
```

**Is that the best method, or is there a better one?**

My real data contain almost a million rows and there are several hundred strings that I need to exclude, and both sets of data are continually growing. So "best" in this context means fastest and needing the least computing power.

---

This is not a duplicate of [R Subset Dataset Using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640562/r-subset-dataset-using-regular-expression), because that question does not address my question of whether subsetting using regular expressions is the *best* method.

Comment: You'll definitely want to look into `grepl`. Also, you can probably clean it up a bit with a `for` loop instead of `while`. But there are likely more elegant solutions, perhaps in the `stringr` package.

Comment: @Jaap Explained.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact `grep` accepts a regular expression, and use the `|` (OR) symbol to simultaneously `grep` everything:

```
> dat[grep("bcd|ghi",dat$words,invert=TRUE),]
  words numbers
2 cdefg       2
6   fgh       6
```

In case you read your strings into an array somehow, such that you have a ton of strings, you can paste them into a `|` delimited string as IceCreamToucan mentions:

```
paste(strings,collapse = '|')
```